# Firestore returning "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I think I'm missing something. I'm trying to get data from my firestore database. I'm sure the collection field is correct, the doc field is correct up until the console.log. When I console.log(credits) it returns a firestore snapshot. However, if I do `console.log(credits.data())` then I get returned undefined. What am I missing?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCredits() {
      await db.collection('users_portfolio').doc(currentUser.email).get().then(credits => {
        console.log(credits.data()
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    } getCredits()
  }, [db, currentUser.email])
```

Comment: It's ok. I figured it out. I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doc.data() returns undefined, it means that your document does not exist. You can verify it this way:

```
if(credits.exist) {
  console.log(credits.data());
}
else {
  console.log(`${credits.ref} does not exist`);
}
```

More info in [the reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data)

Comment: Yep. There was an issue with the naming. I can't believe I was as dumb not to check if the exist tag was true. it turns out I think it had something to do with the underscore(_). When I check, the document didn't exist and when I renamed the collection, it finally worked. tsk tsk